# Counter Strike Source keymap configuration

Tags: counter-strike-source

In CSS it's possible to bind keys to actions.

Is it possible to somehow bind the coordinates of the mouse to the walking action in the game?

Is it possible to find the key names the HID devices have in CSS so I can map them?

If I connect two optical mise to my computer can I configure CSS to distinguish between those two devices and map the keys to different actions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to do something like what RAZER did with portal two? Theoretically, it is possible as you would need the driver for your mouse to read like a joystick. The first mouse could be read as the left stick and the second mouse would be read like another joystick. As far as I know you cannot bind it that way, BUT, if you find a flight stick driver you could try to reinstall the mouse with that driver temporarily or find a program that could read mouse movements as a flight stick and then in CS:S you would map the buttons as walk look and switch weapons.

There is no good program to do want I have outlined. I would try to use a controller for what you want to do instead but that is me. I doubt that a program can differentiate between two optical mouses, and map their actions to joystick functions but it isn't necessarily impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Strafing can be done with a mouse by either putting these commands into your console ("~" key)

```
bind KEYHERE +left, right, +forward, and +backward
```

Entering -forward will simply stop you and not reverse your moving.
As for moving your mouse, mice movement can't control anything. Sorry. As Dan mentioned, these will not get you banned as either putting a ".rc" or a ".cfg" in SteamGamesFolder/Counter Strike Source/cstrike/cfg is expected. Replace SteamGamesFolder with the folder for your Steam games and KEYHERE with a key or button like mouse4.

Answer (score 0):

This will **not** get you VAC banned (depending on how you go about it) - also VAC only looks for genuine cheats, binds are essentially how Counter Strike deals with keyboard buttons, for example in console `bind "space" "+jump"` binds jump to your space bar, you can enter in any other key to bind jump to also.  (put these in your autoconfig.cfg file in your C:\Steam\SteamApps(username)\cstrike\ folder so that they do not get reset when you restart the game).

I don't think something exists for "mousemoveleft" for example, as I fear that's coded in the game itself. Conter Strike will also only take input from one mouse style device at a time, if you plugged in both..  You would be able to use both to control counter strike (but only one at a time and it would only effect looking around) but you couldn't use one as a replacement for a keyboard. You could try hooking up a joystick as Counter strike supports that but it wont really solve your problem I don't think.

It doesn't look like the command exists on further investigation, [here is a list of bind commands and functions for Counter Strike you can make use of in console](http://csstrike.tripod.com/bind.html). Perhaps that might help you further.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way (without risking a VAC ban) of doing the things you wish to do.
It might be possible to do it using third-party tools but there is no way to do it by changing Counter Strike's configs.

Edit:
There is no distinct way for you to separate the input from Mouse A and Mouse B in Counter Strike, if you create a binding that listens to mouse input it would trigger on both devices.